# fullpage.js specific background part when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, fullpage.js

I want to have the background image responsive, when resizing a fullpage.js page, e.g. for mobile/tablet. How can I keep a specific part of the image in the center of the page? 
For example, in this pic, the flower is in the right half. When I resize/use the page on mobile, it should still be visible and not squeezed.
[image]

Comment: Check the examples at [fullpage.js website](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/backgrounds.html). They are using the `cover` property for `background-size`.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `background-size:cover`. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tgthyLq/).

```css
img{    width:100%;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    z-index:999999999999999;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image:url(http://kadeem.london/Image/Kadeem-Laurie-Lisbon-min.jpg);
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7vuy.jpg">
```

`